# PSD of randomly positioned dirac delta train

Tags: power-spectral-density, periodogram

Let $s(t)= \sum_{i=0}^{T} \delta(t-\tau_i)$, where $ \{ \tau_{i} \}$ are random integers between $0,1,\cdots, T-1$. What is the power spectral density of the signal $s(t)$?